# Meaning of __inout_opt given before function parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio

What is the meaning of the keyword given below, when it is given before any function parameter ?

- __inout_opt

Thanks

Comment: I looked online, [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383701(v=vs.85).aspx) was the third hit.

Comment: Can you give an example of where it's used? Also note that symbols starting with double underscore are reserved (and private) for the compiler and standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [header annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383701(v=vs.85).aspx) in the Windows API. `_inout` means the function reads from and writes to the buffer, and `_opt` means it is optional (i.e. it can be null).